# Bulk insert with dynamic table columns in csv

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to do a bulk insert into table in sql server. Only problem i m facing is the csv i need to import from can have variable column. Sometimes it might have 100 and other times it might be 50. I need to create a table depending on the column number in csv and then do bulk insert. Is this process possible? 
Thanking you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

BULK INSERT requires the table to exists, so I would think the best way is simply to create a little application/program in some language you're familiar with that does the work of creating the table for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the date that is variable does not need to be queried directly - then create a table that has columns for the static elements then the serialise the variable elements into a text field or blob.

Comment: Its not date, its just different column that are sometime generated and sometime not thus making the column in CSV inconsistance, but the requirement is to import from Same CSV, we can make different temp table in each import

Comment: I may be missing something - as long as each row as the same number of delimited elements e.g. commas - the length of each element or row does not matter.